# Read value from current (and unsaved) form

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I would like to implement a function to check that there are no features already inserted with the same value in a certain field.

This is the function that I implemented as Action, but during editing *[%id_lavoro%]* always seems to be empty

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
msg = QMessageBox()
l = iface.activeLayer()

expr = QgsExpression( "\"id_lavoro\"=[%id_lavoro%]")
it = l.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = str([i.id() for i in it])
msg.setText(ids)
msg.show()
```

QGIS has a function ([current_value](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#current-value)), but I don't know how to use it in Python code.

[image]

Is there a way to return value of a field in an unsaved form?